Login to Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager after Sonatype Jira Decommissioned
I'm trying to publish an android artifact (.aar) to mavenCentral.
As per Central Sonatype docs https://central.sonatype.org/register/central-portal/
I've created an account using GitHub singin and claimed a namespace as well.
In android studio I already signed artifact using gpg
when run publish from Android studio gradle
I receive following error

Could not GET 'https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/io/github/username/repo_name/0.9-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 401 from server: Content access is protected by token

From early investigation I found out it is happening due to wrong credentials of Sonatype Nexus repository manager.
As Sonatype has decommissioned Sonatype Jira there is no way to create ossrh credentails to login to Sonatype Nexus which is blocking build to publish

when I click on the above URL I get error message saying
"Access Denied
Please login before attempting further requests."

See here for how to get support for this problem:  https://central.sonatype.org/pages/support/#status

Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78581595/22096771
